# BeautifulSoup - Scrape text from start keyword to end keyword

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have the below HTML source code that needs to be scraped. The data includes a table that is not configured with `<table>` tag. I cannot use tags to identify the element as the same tag is used throughout the HTML code. How do I scrape the data to receive the below output? The header line always remains the same, the data within the table varies.

**Code**

```
<p>
    <div class="my-test-class" style="white-space: pre-wrap; font-size: small; font-family: &quot;Courier New&quot;">
        <div class="my-test-class">Random text goes on.........</div>
        <div class="my-test-class"><br></div>
        <div class="my-test-class">Header1 Header2 Header3 Header4 Header5
        </div>
        <div class="my-test-class">--------------------------------------
        </div>
        <div class="my-test-class">A1 B1 C1 D1 E1</div>
        <div class="my-test-class">A2 B2 C2 D2 E2</div>
        <div class="my-test-class">A3 B3 C3 D3 E3</div>
        <div class="my-test-class">--------------------------------------
        </div>
    </div>
</p>
```

Output:

```
Header1 Header2 Header3 Header4 Header5
--------------------------------------
A1 B1 C1 D1 E1
A2 B2 C2 D2 E2
A3 B3 C3 D3 E3
--------------------------------------
```

Scraping code so far:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
soup = BeautifulSoup('''\
<p>
    <div class="my-test-class" style="white-space: pre-wrap; font-size: small; font-family: &quot;Courier New&quot;">
        <div class="my-test-class">Random text goes on.........</div>
        <div class="my-test-class"><br></div>
        <div class="my-test-class">Header1 Header2 Header3 Header4 Header5
        </div>
        <div class="my-test-class">--------------------------------------
        </div>
        <div class="my-test-class">A1 B1 C1 D1 E1</div>
        <div class="my-test-class">A2 B2 C2 D2 E2</div>
        <div class="my-test-class">A3 B3 C3 D3 E3</div>
        <div class="my-test-class">--------------------------------------
        </div>
    </div>
</p>
''')

h = soup.find_all(text=re.compile('Header1*'))
print(h)
```

Comment: What values are inside the table? Just numbers or strings with whitespaces?

Answer (score 1):

You can find header and then `.find_next_siblings()` is your table:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

txt = '''<p>
    <div class="my-test-class" style="white-space: pre-wrap; font-size: small; font-family: &quot;Courier New&quot;">
        <div class="my-test-class">Random text goes on.........</div>
        <div class="my-test-class"><br></div>
        <div class="my-test-class">Header1 Header2 Header3 Header4 Header5
        </div>
        <div class="my-test-class">--------------------------------------
        </div>
        <div class="my-test-class">A1 B1 C1 D1 E1</div>
        <div class="my-test-class">A2 B2 C2 D2 E2</div>
        <div class="my-test-class">A3 B3 C3 D3 E3</div>
        <div class="my-test-class">--------------------------------------
        </div>
    </div>
</p>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

header = soup.find(text=lambda t: '----' in t).parent.find_previous()

print(header.text)
print(*[tag.get_text(strip=True) for tag in header.find_next_siblings()], sep='\n')
```

Prints:

```
Header1 Header2 Header3 Header4 Header5
        
--------------------------------------
A1 B1 C1 D1 E1
A2 B2 C2 D2 E2
A3 B3 C3 D3 E3
--------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help you:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
soup = BeautifulSoup('''\
<p>
    <div class="my-test-class" style="white-space: pre-wrap; font-size: small; font-family: &quot;Courier New&quot;">
        <div class="my-test-class">Random text goes on.........</div>
        <div class="my-test-class"><br></div>
        <div class="my-test-class">Header1 Header2 Header3 Header4 Header5
        </div>
        <div class="my-test-class">--------------------------------------
        </div>
        <div class="my-test-class">A1 B1 C1 D1 E1</div>
        <div class="my-test-class">A2 B2 C2 D2 E2</div>
        <div class="my-test-class">A3 B3 C3 D3 E3</div>
        <div class="my-test-class">--------------------------------------
        </div>
    </div>
</p>
''', 'html5lib')

txt = soup.find_all('div', class_ = "my-test-class", text=True)
txt = [elem.text.strip() for elem in txt]
pattern = re.compile('[A-Z][0-9]')

[print(elem) for elem in txt if 'Header' in elem or '-' in elem or pattern.match(elem)]
```

Output:

```
Header1 Header2 Header3 Header4 Header5
--------------------------------------     
A1 B1 C1 D1 E1
A2 B2 C2 D2 E2
A3 B3 C3 D3 E3
--------------------------------------
```